# Memory allocation error when reading multiple files

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to open 6 different files (at least) and then read the number of lines in each file, which should be about 20,000 lines each. I've read some posts on this forum about how to do that as I'm a newbie, and I've tried to implement it for my purposes.

I can do this individually without any problem, but when I try to read in all the files, I get an error message. I get either the "Killed: 9" error message or a malloc error:

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=63032829050880) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

What does this error mean regarding memory allocation? What am I doing wrong? How do I go about correcting this?

```
   PROGRAM X

   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER :: J,IO,NFILES,NLINES
   CHARACTER (LEN=128) :: FILENAME

   NFILES = 6

   NLINES = 0

   DO J = 0,NFILES-1
      WRITE(FILENAME,'(A,I7.7,A)') 'data_',J*200,'.txt'
      OPEN(1,FILE='FILENAME',FORM='FORMATTED')
      DO
         READ(1,*,IOSTAT=IO)
         IF (IO/=0) EXIT
         NLINES = NLINES + 1
      END DO
      WRITE(*,*) NLINES
      CLOSE(1)
   END DO

   END PROGRAM X
```

I am using gfortran to compile.

---

**UPDATE**

I created 6 test files, data_0000000.txt, data_0000200.txt, ..., data_0001000.txt, each with less than 10 lines where there are less than 100 characters in each line. Unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you also follow the advise of changing unit 1 to e.g unit 100.

Comment: @albert Yes, I changed it to 10 (I also tried 100).

Comment: did you already try to compile with boundary checking, debug options on and run with gdb to see where it throws the error?

Comment: please compile with `gfortran -g -O0 -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace`

Comment: @chw21 Thank you! In my full code (not my minimal example posted here) I was allocating memory using some uninitialized variables. D'oh! Sorry to bother everyone. Everything works now as desired. Do you think, though, that you might explain what those compiler options are?

Comment: `-g` -- include debug symbols in the executable. `-O0` no optimization. `-Wall` Enable all compile time warnings. `-fcheck=all` enable run time checks. `-fbacktrace` more elaborate stack trace printed on crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory disclaimer: If you just want to know the number of lines in a file, use `wc -l <filename>`. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

I write this not necessarily because I think you didn't know that, but because someone else might come along, and think they need to write their own program to get the number of lines of files.

As for your question: I don't know why you get a `malloc` error. Maybe tell us which compiler and system you're using (including versions)? That said, there are three things that I noticed when reading your code:

1. You create a variable `FILENAME`, but then you don't use it. You're quoting it: `FILE='FILENAME'` which means that the open command looks for a file literally called `FILENAME`, not for a file with the name stored in the variable `FILENAME`. Remove the quotes:

   ```
   OPEN(1, FILENAME=FILENAME, FORM='FORMATTED')
   ```
2. You use the unit number `1` -- that is dangerous. Different version of Fortran use specific unit numbers for specific uses. Use a handle far larger (at least 10, or more), or, even better, use the `newunit` descriptor in the open statement:

   ```
   INTEGER :: u

   OPEN(NEWUNIT=u, FILE=FILENAME, ACTION='READ', FORM='FORMATTED')

   READ(u, *, IOSTAT=IO)

   CLOSE(u)
   ```
3. You're not resetting the `NLINES` variable to 0 between files. The program will print a cumulative sum, not the number of lines for each file directly.

Comment: No I can't. Mainly because I can't even reproduce the `malloc` error myself. So all I can do is go through the various issues with the code and tell him to fix it. I would have done it as a comment, but it was getting too long.

Comment: But you're right, I didn't address the specific question, and I shouldn't have claimed otherwise. After the time spent trying to recreate the error and formulating my solution, I forgot the specifics of the question. My bad. I changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same error, even after I implement the changes you suggest. I'm trying to read in the number of lines for each of hundreds of input files (why the command line entry you gave in point #1 would be impractical) so that I can then do some math on the values that I read. Is there a better way to do it in principle than the way I'm going about it? I'm really stuck!

Comment: I'm using `gfortran` and Fortran 90, if that matters.

Comment: You could still consider the command line entry as a way of simplifying the solution. A command like "wc -l data_* > linecounts" would create one file containing a list of all the line counts for all the files matching data_*.  You could then just open the one file to process the numbers.

Comment: I think the error comes from using some undefined value of `NLINES` after an error in reading. I highly suggest not just using `IOSTAT` for the `read`, but also for the `open`. I also suggest distinguishing positive and negative values returned by `read` in `iostat`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @chw21's response, if your sole purpose is to count the number of records (lines) in a file, here is a modular solution and a test program along with it (the counting is done inside subroutine `getNumRecordInFile()`):

```
module NumRecord_mod

    implicit none

    type :: Err_type
        logical                     :: occurred = .false.
        integer                     :: stat     = -huge(0)
        character(:), allocatable   :: msg
    end type Err_type

contains

    ! returns the number of lines in a file.
    subroutine getNumRecordInFile(filePath,numRecord,Err)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in)    :: filePath
        integer, intent(out)            :: numRecord
        type(Err_type), intent(out)     :: Err
        character(len=8)                :: record
        integer                         :: fileUnit
        logical                         :: fileExists, isOpen
        integer                         :: iostat

        character(*), parameter         :: PROCEDURE_NAME = "@getNumRecordInFile()"

        Err%occurred = .false.
        Err%msg = ""

        ! Check if file exists
        inquire( file=filePath, exist=fileExists, opened=isOpen, number=fileUnit, iostat=Err%stat )
        if (Err%stat/=0) then
            Err%occurred = .true.
            Err%msg = PROCEDURE_NAME // ": Error occurred while inquiring the status of file='" // filePath // "'."
            return
        end if
        if (.not.fileExists) then
            Err%occurred = .true.
            Err%msg = PROCEDURE_NAME // ": The input file='" // filePath // "' does not exist."
            return
        end if
        if (isOpen) close(unit=fileUnit,iostat=Err%stat)
        if (Err%stat>0) then
            Err%occurred = .true.
            Err%msg = PROCEDURE_NAME // ": Error occurred while attempting to close the open input file='" // filePath // "'."
            return
        end if

        open(newunit=fileUnit,file=filePath,status="old",iostat=Err%stat)
        if (Err%stat>0) then
            Err%occurred = .true.
            Err%msg = PROCEDURE_NAME // ": Error occurred while opening input file='" // filePath // "'."
            return
        end if

        numRecord = 0
        do
            read(fileUnit,'(A)',iostat=iostat) record
            if(iostat==0) then
                numRecord = numRecord + 1
                cycle
            elseif(is_iostat_end(iostat)) then
                exit
            else
                Err%occurred = .true.
                Err%stat = iostat
                Err%msg = PROCEDURE_NAME // ": Error occurred while reading input file='" // filePath // "'."
                return
            end if
        end do
        close(fileUnit,iostat=Err%stat)
        if (Err%stat>0) then
            Err%occurred = .true.
            Err%msg =   PROCEDURE_NAME // ": Error occurred while attempting to close the open input file='" // &
                        filePath // "' after counting the number of records in file."
            return
        end if

    end subroutine getNumRecordInFile


end module NumRecord_mod

program test_numRecord
    use NumRecord_mod
    implicit none
    type(Err_type)              :: Err
    integer                     :: numRecord
    character(:), allocatable   :: filePath
    filePath = "main.f95"
    call getNumRecordInFile(filePath=filePath,numRecord=numRecord,Err=Err)
    if (Err%occurred) then
        write(*,*) Err%msg
        write(*,*) Err%stat
        error stop
    else
        write(*,*) "Total number of records in file='" // filePath // "': ", numRecord
    end if
end program test_numRecord
```

Now if you put this code in a file named "main.f95" and compile it under Fortran 2008 standard, then it should output the number of lines in your "main.f95" file, which should be something like the following:

```
$gfortran -std=f2008 *.f95 -o main
$main
 Total number of records in file='main.f95':           98
```

For testing, you can simply copy paste the entire code in the online Fortran compiler here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php
But keep in mind to change the compile option `-std=f95` to `-std=f2008` by going to `Project -> Compile Options` before executing the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this change (declaration and read line), there was no variable specified where the line contents shall go, here insert now  dummy...

```
character(len=1000) :: dummy
...
READ(u, '(a)' , IOSTAT=IO) dummy
....
```

Comment: A `read` statement with an empty argument list is perfectly fine. It poses no problem at all, it just skips one line in the file.